# How to print through local or network printer in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, textbox, printers

I want to select one of installed printer on my computer and print through it but my combobox doesn't display the printers on my machine but rather print to my terminal in my IDE .

Have been trying this for days with arriving at the solution to do this.Have installed the win32print module to after reading about it.This my code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import win32print



def installed_printer():
    printers = win32print.EnumPrinters(2)
      for p in printers:
         return(p)



def locprinter():
    pt = Toplevel()
    pt.geometry("250x250")
    pt.title("choose printer")
    LABEL = Label(pt, text="select Printer").pack()
    PRCOMBO = ttk.Combobox(pt, width=35, 
    textvariable=installed_printer).pack()
    BUTTON = ttk.Button(pt, text="refresh", 
    command=installed_printer).pack()


root = Tk()
root.title("printer selection in tkinter")
root.geometry("400x400")


menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

file_menu = Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="printer", command=locprinter)


LAB = Label(root, text="Comment")
T2 = Text(root, width=40, height=10)


def INFO():
print(T2.get("1.0", END))


Print_Button = Button(root, text ="Print", command = 
INFO).place(x=180,y=250)

LAB.pack()
T2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How can i achieve this as i want to print the content in my Text box with tkinter framework.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted to create?

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import win32api
import win32print
import tempfile



def installed_printer():
    printers = win32print.EnumPrinters(2)
    for p in printers:
        return(p)

printerdef = ''

def locprinter():
    pt = Toplevel()
    pt.geometry("250x250")
    pt.title("choose printer")
    var1 = StringVar()
    LABEL = Label(pt, text="select Printer").pack()
    PRCOMBO = ttk.Combobox(pt, width=35,textvariable=var1)
    print_list = []
    printers = list(win32print.EnumPrinters(2))
    for i in printers:
        print_list.append(i[2])
    print(print_list)
    # Put printers in combobox
    PRCOMBO['values'] = print_list
    PRCOMBO.pack()
    def select():
        global printerdef
        printerdef = PRCOMBO.get()
        pt.destroy()
    BUTTON = ttk.Button(pt, text="Done",command=select).pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("printer selection in tkinter")
root.geometry("400x400")


menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

file_menu = Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="printer", command=locprinter)


LAB = Label(root, text="Comment")
T2 = Text(root, width=40, height=10, wrap=WORD)


def INFO():
    printText = T2.get("1.0", END)
    print(printText)
    print(printerdef)
    filename = tempfile.mktemp(".txt")
    open(filename, "w").write(printText)
    # Bellow is call to print text from T2 textbox
    win32api.ShellExecute(
        0,
        "printto",
        filename,
        '"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter(),
        ".",
        0
    )


Print_Button = Button(root, text ="Print", command=INFO).place(x=180,y=250)

LAB.pack()
T2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please explain the difference and why you did these changes to the logger ?

Comment: With the above code the installed printer output to the combox but when i type the content and want to print the selected prrinter does not print the content and please kindly comment your code .

Comment: Page to small to print try using smaller font.

Comment: @Goran do have any suggestions to make it work better

Comment: I can try in monday when I come back from trip.

Comment: @Goran please are you back

Comment: Hi. Yeah I am back. The error it is throwing is because your Notepad config. Try to print directly from notepad and if error is the same try to reconfigure it.

Comment: when i print from notepad it doesn't give any error, the printer is able to execute the job

Comment: @Goran any response from you on this question

Comment: Try the code now a made word wrap in textbox. I don't have errors when printing so it is hard to find the bug in you'r PC.